# Get 24 hours exact time row or next up row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get the exact time row by second of 24 hours ago, or the row coming next of 48 hours.

Let's show you an example to understand well my goal:

Current time is: `2018-07-30 22:43:09`

I have this rows in my database:

```
1- 2018-07-29 10:21:00
2- 2018-07-29 22:43:09
3- 2018-07-28 12:40:11
```

So, the expected result for this rows is:

```
Row number 2.
```

So, here next rows:

```
1- 2018-07-30 12:31:00
2- 2018-07-29 21:21:00
3- 2018-07-28 01:13:41
4- 2018-07-27 12:30:21
```

The expected result here:

```
Will be row number 3.
```

**What i did ?**

```
SELECT
    `info`, `date`
FROM mytable
WHERE id='1' AND date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Tested my query with:**

Current time: `2018-07-30 18:39:55`

Rows:

```
1- 2018-07-30 18:42:47
2- 2018-07-29 23:16:47
3- 2018-07-29 10:41:19
```

Result is: `Row number 2`

It supposed to be, or i expect the result: `Row 3.`

I made an online training link here:
http://rextester.com/MPXR66606

What i made wrong please ?

Comment: Since you're using two different formats for the dates in this post, what format is the 'date' column in your database in? Does it match the format that DATE_SUB() returns?

Comment: Three formats actually. `Current time` is in yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss format while the rows below it are in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (days and months are switched).

Comment: @Stanzi1791 I use same format as the database sir.

Comment: No, i use exact same format as the database, the rows are just examples.

Comment: Try casting both dates: `WHERE id='1' AND cast(date as date) <= cast(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) as date) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Stanzi1791 already tried but do not work, the format is same as the database, all my values (rows) stored using `now()`. But after many searches, i notice that the problem of this query do not take in count the time, so here is the problem and can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: You mean your database rows are just yyyy-mm-dd without time?

Comment: @Stanzi1791 No i mean my database is in this format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:iii:ss, it's stored using `now()`. I mean problem of request i think it not take the time in count.

Comment: Ah I see. Are you using Mysql? According to their documentation the DATE_SUB() function should return a DATETIME if its first argument is a DATETIME, which is it in your case. And your rows are formattted as DATETIME too so I don't see what else you could be doing wrong.

Comment: One more thing I could find, `date` is a reserved word in mysql, so you could try renaming your date column to something other than date and see if that helps?

Comment: @Stanzi1791 i am using `date` inside "`", this prevent confusing with reserved words. I think the query is correct but not give exact result, i need to know the problem where it is :(

Comment: @Stanzi1791 date is not a reserved word

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Check live example here: http://rextester.com/MPXR66606

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. If I execute `select '2018-07-29 23:16:47' <= DATE_SUB('2018-07-30 18:39:55', INTERVAL 24 HOUR);`, I get `0`. I suspect either your _"current date"_ or the data in your database is not what you think it is. Demo ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/51993

Comment: @BenMarson why are you using `varchar(19)` to store date/time objects? In any case, there's some strange data coming out of that _rextester_ site so I wouldn't recommend using it. Here's your demo working as expected ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e48a4c/2